# Problema de login en PHP con codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, login

Muy buenas a todos, tengo problema con el login del sistema que estoy haciendo lo que sucede es que al entrar a la ventana de login este manda datos nulos automaticamente y aunque ponga los datos de email y contraseña junto al tipo de usuario, este lo sigue tomando nulo y me devuelve al login. espero me puedan ayudar ya he intentado de todo y no puedo arreglarlo.

Este es mi Control dashboard

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model([
        'dashboard_model',
        'setting_model'
    ]);
}

public function index()
{ 
    if ($this->session->userdata('isLogIn') === true) 
        redirect('dashboard/home'); 
    #-------------------------------#
    $data['title'] = "Login"; 
    #-------------------------------#
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','required|max_length[50]|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_role','User role','required');
    #-------------------------------#
    $data['user'] = (object)$postData = [
        'email'     => $this->input->post('email',true),
        'password'  => $this->input->post('password',true),
        'user_role' => $this->input->post('user_role',true),
    ]; var_dump($postData);
    #-------------------------------#
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
        //check user data
        $check_user = $this->dashboard_model->check_user($postData);
        echo $check_user;
        echo '<p>entro al if</p>';

        if ($check_user->num_rows() === 1) {
            //retrive setting data and store to session
            $setting = $this->setting_model->read($postData);

            //store data in session
            $this->session->set_userdata([
                'isLogIn'   => true,
                'user_id'   => $check_user->row()->user_id,
                'email'     => $check_user->row()->email,
                'fullname'  => $check_user->row()->firstname.' '.$check_user->row()->lastname,
                'user_role' => $check_user->row()->user_role,
                'picture'   => $check_user->row()->picture, 
                'title'     => (!empty($setting->title)?$setting->title:null),
                'address'   => (!empty($setting->description)?$setting->description:null),
                'logo'      => (!empty($setting->logo)?$setting->logo:null),
                'favicon'      => (!empty($setting->favicon)?$setting->favicon:null),
                'footer_text' => (!empty($setting->footer_text)?$setting->footer_text:null),
            ]);
            //redirect to dashboard home page
            redirect('dashboard/home');
        } else {
            #set exception message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('exception',"Incorrect email/password!");
            //redirect to login form
            redirect('login');
        }

    } else {
        echo '<p>Hola Mundo</p>';
        var_dump($postData);
        $this->load->view('layout/login_wrapper',$data);
    } 
}  

public function home()
{   
    if ($this->session->userdata('isLogIn') == false) 
        redirect('login'); 
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_role') == 2) 
        redirect('report/assign_to_me'); 
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_role') == 3) 
        redirect('report/assign_by_me'); 

    $data['title'] = "Home";
    #------------------------------#
    $data['notify'] = $this->dashboard_model->notify(); 
    $data['enquires'] = $this->dashboard_model->enquiry();  
    $data['chart'] = $this->dashboard_model->chart();    
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('home',$data,true);
    $this->load->view('layout/main_wrapper',$data);
} 

public function profile()
{ 
    if ($this->session->userdata('isLogIn') == false) 
        redirect('login'); 
    $data['title'] = "Profile";
    #------------------------------# 
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $data['user']    = $this->dashboard_model->read_by_id($user_id);
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('profile',$data,true);
    $this->load->view('layout/main_wrapper',$data);
} 

public function logout()
{  
    $this->session->sess_destroy(); 
    redirect('login');
}  }
```

Ahora estos son mis modelos el primero del dashboard

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model {

        private $table = "user";

        public function check_user($data = [])
        {
            return $this->db->select("*")
                ->from($this->table)
                ->where('email',$data['email'])
                ->where('password',$data['password'])
                ->where('user_role',$data['user_role'])
                ->where('status',1)
                ->get();
        } 

        public function read_by_id($user_id = null)
        {
            return $this->db->select("*")
                ->from($this->table)
                ->where('user_id',$user_id)
                ->get()
                ->row();
        } 

        public function notify()
        {
            return $this->db->query('
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_app,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patient) AS total_patient,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE user_role = 2) AS total_doctor,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE user_role = 3) AS total_representative
    FROM appointment
            ')
            ->row();
        }

        public function enquiry()
        {
            return $this->db->select('enquiry_id, name, email, enquiry')
                ->from('enquiry')
                ->limit(4)
                ->order_by('checked','asc')
                ->order_by('created_date','desc')
                ->order_by('enquiry_id','desc')
                ->get()
                ->result();
        }


        public function chart()
        {
            $qu

ery1 =  $this->db->query('
            SELECT  
                create_date AS date,
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM create_date) AS month,
                COUNT(patient_id) AS patient
            FROM patient
            WHERE create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM create_date)
        ')
        ->result(); 

        $query2 = $this->db->query('
            SELECT 
                create_date AS date,
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM create_date) AS month,
                COUNT(appointment_id) AS appointment
            FROM appointment
            WHERE create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM create_date)
        ')
        ->result(); 

        return [$query1,$query2]; 
    }}
```

Este es de settings

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Setting_model extends CI_Model {


private $table = "setting";

public function create($data = [])
{    
    return $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
}

public function read()
{
    return $this->db->select("*")
        ->from($this->table)
        ->get()
        ->row();
} 

public function update($data = [])
{
    return $this->db->where('setting_id',$data['setting_id'])
        ->update($this->table,$data); 
} }
```

Formulario de login (cabe destacar que uso como framework CodeIniter)

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <?php echo form_open('login'); ?>
     <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <?php
              $userRoles = [
                  ''  => 'Select user role',
                  '1' => 'Admin',
                  '2' => 'Doctor',
                  '3' => 'Representative' 
              ];
           echo form_dropdown('user_role', $userRoles, $user->user_role, 'class="form-control" id="blood_group" ');?>
           </div> 
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
            </fieldset>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Deberías de compartir tu formulario para saber si lo estas enviando correctamente.

Comment: Coloca tu formulario para ver a donde estas apuntando al hacer el `submit`

Comment: ya añadí el formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer tu `form` de esta forma y mandarlo a tu controlador `dashboard` donde tendrías  una función `login` y mandar ahí tus datos:

```html
<form class="form-login" method="POST" action="<?= base_url(); >index.php/dashboard/login">

     <div class="form-row input-login">
          <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="usuario" required>
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-row input-login">
         <div class="col">
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="contraseña" required>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-row input-login">
         <div class="col">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login" value="Iniciar" name="submit">
         </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

La variable `base_url` esta en `config/config.php` y aparece de la siguiente manera:

```php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/miProyecto/'
```

Este seria tu controlador `dashboard`:

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class dashboard extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index()
   {
       // hacer algo
   }

   public function login()
   {
       // Aqui cachas tus datos enviados y haces todas tus validaciones
       $user = $this->input->post('username');
       $pass = $this->input->post('password');

       $response = $this->validateUser($user, $pass);

       if($response != '0')
       {

           $data = array(
               'usuario' => $user,
               'login' => true
           );

           $this->session->set_userdata($data);
           redirect('/');

       }else 
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error_login', 1);
           redirect('/');
       }
   }

   public function logout()
   {
       $this->session->sess_destroy();
       redirect('/');
   }

}
```

Espero que con el ejemplo te puedas guiar, suerte.

> Nota: en el ejemplo solo mando usuario y contraseña, ahí faltaría meter el rol del usuario que muestras en tu ejemplo pero como te recuerdo es un ejemplo de como lo podrías hacer.

Comment: Si funciona, parece que si necesitaba una función para validar los datos pasaba que al no tener todo dentro de una función los datos no llegaban a la validación y entraba siempre al else que me redireccionaba al login.